# How can someone else sell a car with my name also on the paperwork?

Tags: loans, car

I just found out from my x that he got a new car but my name was still on the old one and I never signed any paperwork when he traded it in. How can a car dealership do that with my name still on it?

Comment: I'm asking how he could trade it in without me signing for it cause my name was on the loan and the title

Comment: Loan does not directly matter; see all the past discussion here about the hazards of being a chi-signer. Title.... where are you located? That may depend on state laws or something of that sort.

Comment: I'm in New Hampshire I know I was told when I got the divorce papers I can take them down to the town hall and it will cost me 10.00 to switch it over

Answer (score 9):

In general the purchaser could not get the title in their name unless the title could be cleared.

When there was a loan on the vehicle there were three names on the title: You, your-x and the bank.

When the loan was paid the bank released their lien against the title.

There are a couple of ways your name could have been removed:

- the divorce decree divided the assets. And the settlement papers directed that your name be removed from the title.
- At some point you signed a quit claim deed. The deed told the world you were giving up your rights.
- some sort of fraud.

If the fraud was done in person at the DMV or the dealer, they would have wanted to see and make a copy of the drivers licenses. If *'you'* weren't there your-x would have needed to present a notarized document that would meet the requirements.

So check the divorce/settlement documents to make sure they don't include a copy of something directing DMV to remove your name. If you can't find it, talk to your divorce attorney for advice.

Comment: Very thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, I've heard of two distinguished ways that two people can be named on a title:

1. Alice and Bob
2. Alice *or* Bob

In the first case, both Alice and Bob must be present to make any changes, such as transfer of title. In the second case, *either* party may make changes unilaterally.